# Creating a model in Django

Tags: django-models

I created 2 models News and Category in Django.

```
from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Заголовок')
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Текст')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Время создания')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Время создания')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/%y/%m/%d', null='True', blank='True',
                              verbose_name='Фото')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Публикация')


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Категория')
```

Then I made migrations and went to SQLiteStudio. There I see model News, but there's no model Category.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uunP.jpg)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you create and made migrations *after* you defined the `Category`? Does `Category` appear in the migrations file?

Comment: No. First I difined the News, create and made migraations. Then I defined the Category. When I tried to create migrations i'v got an error.  I deleted all migration files and created and made migrations again

Comment: Please don't delete migrations, definitely not the ones that you already migrated, since now the new migration can not be applied either, since that will first try to create a `news` table, which already exists...